# Google maps resize not working after clicking Back button on Ember

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ember.js

I'm having some issues in an Ember app when using the Back button to navigate back to a page with a Google map using a Fusion Table layer. On a fresh page load, this is how it looks:

[image: On fresh page load]

After clicking one of the pins and going to another view, when I click the back button, the following happens:

[image: After clicking back]

The size and position of the gray bars varies.

I've tried doing `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` and calling `map.setZoom(map.getZoom())` to no effect. I've made sure the containers have width/height as well.

Just to be clear, this is an Ember application,so clicking on the back button is not a full page reload, but rather just a swapping out of Controllers/Views by Ember. I was hoping to just need to trigger the resize on such a transition, but the resize seems to not be enough, even when called directly from the console.

One more thing, other transitions to the page (e.g. by clicking on other elements that trigger either a `link-to` or a `transitionTo` to the map) work fine. It's only when the transition happens with the Back button that the map goes awry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered that I actually managed to "fix" this issue but never got around to posting the answer.

What was happening in my case was that the code I was using was trying to optimize rendering time by keeping the map canvas around by attaching it to the `body` tag when the view was [removed](https://github.com/radman/ember-map/blob/master/app/scripts/components/ember-map-component.coffee#L35) in `willDestroyElement` and then moving it back into the view whenever the view was [loaded](https://github.com/radman/ember-map/blob/master/app/scripts/components/ember-map-component.coffee#L16) again in `didInsertElement`. Apparently Google maps was having none of it. So I ended up forking the code and updating so that the map was discarded and a new instance was created whenever the view was displayed.